# Parsing cron expression

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm building my own scheduler and I took the first step by creating a cron expression parser.

---

To test it I used this expression to cover each case. *(I guess the 52W is wrong but this doesn't matter yet - validation comes later).*

```
"14,18,3-39/3,52 0/5 14,18,3-39,52W ? JAN,MAR,SEP MON-WED,FRI#3 2002-2010"
```

---

## Core

It starts with the tokenizer that has only one method with a loop that builds each token. It requires special handling of extensions like `W`, `L` or `#`.

```
class CronExpressionTokenizer
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<char, TokenType> TokenTypes = new Dictionary<char, TokenType>
    {
        [' '] = TokenType.FieldSeparator,
        [','] = TokenType.ListItemSeparator,
        ['-'] = TokenType.RangeSeparator,
        ['/'] = TokenType.StepSeparator,
        ['*'] = TokenType.Blank,
        ['?'] = TokenType.Blank,
        ['L'] = TokenType.Extension,
        ['W'] = TokenType.Extension,
        ['#'] = TokenType.Extension,
    };

    public static IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize(string text)
    {
        var position = (int?)null;
        var value = new StringBuilder();
        var lastTokenType = TokenType.None;

        var updateLastTokenType = new Func<Token, Token>(t => { lastTokenType = t.Type; return t; });

        for (var i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            var c = text[i];

            var tokenType = TokenType.None;
            if (TokenTypes.TryGetValue(c, out tokenType))
            {
                // Special extension handling.
                var isNotExtension =
                    // Parsed as extension...
                    tokenType == TokenType.Extension &&
                    // but a "W" not after a value or field-separator.
                    (c == 'W' && (lastTokenType != TokenType.Value || lastTokenType == TokenType.FieldSeparator));

                if (isNotExtension)
                {
                    lastTokenType = TokenType.Value;
                    position = position ?? i;
                    value.Append(c);
                    continue;
                }

                if (value.Any())
                {
                    yield return updateLastTokenType(new Token
                    {
                        Type = TokenType.Value,
                        Position = position.Value,
                        Value = value.ToString()
                    });
                    lastTokenType = TokenType.Value;
                    position = i + 1;
                    value = new StringBuilder();
                }

                yield return updateLastTokenType(new Token
                {
                    Type = tokenType,
                    Position = i,
                    Value = c.ToString()
                });

                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                lastTokenType = TokenType.Value;
                position = position ?? i;
                value.Append(c);
            }
        }

        if (value.Any())
        {
            yield return new Token
            {
                Type = TokenType.Value,
                Position = position.Value,
                Value = value.ToString()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The result for the test expression is:

```
Type                Position    Value
Value               0           14
ListItemSeparator   2           ,
Value               3           18
ListItemSeparator   5           ,
Value               6           3
RangeSeparator      7           -
Value               8           39
StepSeparator       10          /
Value               11          3
ListItemSeparator   12          ,
Value               13          52
FieldSeparator      15   
Value               16          0
StepSeparator       17          /
Value               18          5
FieldSeparator      19   
Value               20          14
ListItemSeparator   22          ,
Value               23          18
ListItemSeparator   25          ,
Value               26          3
RangeSeparator      27          -
Value               28          39
ListItemSeparator   30          ,
Value               31          52
Extension           33          W
FieldSeparator      34   
Value               34          JAN
Blank               35          ?
FieldSeparator      36   
ListItemSeparator   40          ,
Value               41          MAR
ListItemSeparator   44          ,
Value               45          SEP
FieldSeparator      48   
Value               49          MON
RangeSeparator      52          -
Value               53          WED
ListItemSeparator   56          ,
Value               57          FRI
Extension           60          #
Value               61          3
FieldSeparator      62   
Value               63          2002
RangeSeparator      67          -
Value               68          2010
```

---

Then the `CronExpressionParser` comes in play. It groups all tokens into fields `TokenGroup` and creates `Subexpression`s. It also parses names of months and days of week. This for names and ordinal extensions I use three dictionaries.

```
class CronExpressionParser
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> DaysOfWeek = new[]
    {
        "SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"
    }
    .Select((dayOfWeek, index) => new { dayOfWeek, index }).ToDictionary(x => x.dayOfWeek, x => x.index + 1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> Months = new[]
    {
        "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
    }
    .Select((month, index) => new { month, index }).ToDictionary(x => x.month, x => x.index + 1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, CronExtension> Extensions = new Dictionary<string, CronExtension>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        ["1"] = CronExtension.First,
        ["2"] = CronExtension.Second,
        ["3"] = CronExtension.Third,
        ["4"] = CronExtension.Fourth,
        ["5"] = CronExtension.Fifth,
        ["L"] = CronExtension.Last,
        ["W"] = CronExtension.Weekday,
    };

    public static IEnumerable<Subexpression> Parse(IEnumerable<Token> tokens)
    {
        var tokenGroups = GroupTokens(tokens);
        foreach (var tokenGroup in tokenGroups)
        {
            var subexpression = ParseSubexpression(tokenGroup);
            yield return subexpression;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type, Token>> GroupTokens(IEnumerable<Token> tokens)
    {
        var subexpressionTypes = new Queue<Type>(new[]
        {
            typeof(Second),
            typeof(Minute),
            typeof(Hour),
            typeof(DayOfMonth),
            typeof(Month),
            typeof(DayOfWeek),
            typeof(Year)
        });

        var field = new List<Token>();

        foreach (var token in tokens)
        {
            if (token.Type == TokenType.FieldSeparator)
            {
                yield return new TokenGrouping(subexpressionTypes.Dequeue(), field);
                field = new List<Token>();
                continue;
            }

            field.Add(token);
        }

        yield return new TokenGrouping(subexpressionTypes.Dequeue(), field);
    }

    private static Subexpression ParseSubexpression(IGrouping<Type, Token> tokenGroup)
    {
        var ranges = new List<CronRange>();

        var range = (CronRange?)null;
        var lastTokenType = TokenType.None;

        foreach (var token in tokenGroup)
        {
            if (token.Type == TokenType.Value)
            {
                var value = 0;
                var valueParsed =
                    int.TryParse(token.Value, out value) ||
                    DaysOfWeek.TryGetValue(token.Value, out value) ||
                    Months.TryGetValue(token.Value, out value);

                if (!valueParsed)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Invalid value \"{token.Value}\" at {token.Position}.");
                }

                range = range ?? CronRange.Empty.SetMin(value).SetMax(value);

                if (lastTokenType == TokenType.ListItemSeparator)
                {
                    ranges.Add(range.Value);
                    range = CronRange.Empty.SetMin(value).SetMax(value);
                }

                if (lastTokenType == TokenType.RangeSeparator)
                {
                    range = range.SetMax(value);
                }

                if (lastTokenType == TokenType.StepSeparator)
                {
                    range = range.SetStep(value);
                }
            }

            var canUpdateExtension = new[] { lastTokenType, token.Type }.Any(t => t == TokenType.Extension) && token.Value != "#";
            if (canUpdateExtension)
            {
                ranges.Add(range.SetExtension(Extensions[token.Value]));
                range = null;
            }

            lastTokenType = token.Type;
        }

        if (range.HasValue)
        {
            ranges.Add(range.Value);
        }

        return (Subexpression)Activator.CreateInstance(tokenGroup.Key, ranges);
    }
}
```

---

I store all values as `CronRange`. If it's a single value then the min and max are equal. Some values can have a step or an extension.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
struct CronRange
{
    public CronRange(int min, int max, int step, CronExtension extension)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
        Step = step;
        Extension = extension;
    }

    public static CronRange Empty => new CronRange();

    public int Min { get; }
    public int Max { get; }
    public int Step { get; }
    public CronExtension Extension { get; }

    private string DebuggerDisplay => ToString();

    public override string ToString() => $"Min = {Min} Max = {Max} Step = {Step} Extension = {Extension}";
}
```

---

## Auxiliary types

The `Token` and two enums for their types and entensions:

```
enum TokenType
{
    None,
    Blank,
    FieldSeparator,
    ListItemSeparator,
    RangeSeparator,
    StepSeparator,
    Value,
    Extension,
}

enum CronExtension
{
    None,
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
    Fourth,
    Fifth,
    Last,
    Weekday,
}

class Token
{
    public TokenType Type { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

The `TokenGrouping` for each field:

```
class TokenGrouping : IGrouping<Type, Token>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Token> _tokens;
    public TokenGrouping(Type key, IEnumerable<Token> tokens)
    {
        Key = key;
        _tokens = tokens;
    }
    public Type Key { get; }

    public IEnumerator<Token> GetEnumerator() => _tokens.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

---

For future use I define a couple of classes for each field. They're empty but later they will check the `DateTime` and validate if the `TokenGroup` has valid values.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
abstract
class Subexpression
{
    protected Subexpression(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges)
    {
        Ranges = ranges;
    }
    protected IEnumerable<CronRange> Ranges { get; }

    private string DebuggerDisplay => ToString();

    public override string ToString() => $"Ranges = [{string.Join(", ", Ranges.Select(r => $"{{{r}}}"))}]";
}
class Second : Subexpression { public Second(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(ranges) { } }
class Minute : Subexpression { public Minute(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(ranges) { } }
class Hour : Subexpression { public Hour(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(ranges) { } }
class DayOfMonth : Subexpression { public DayOfMonth(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(ranges) { } }
class Month : Subexpression { public Month(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(ranges) { } }
class DayOfWeek : Subexpression { public DayOfWeek(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(ranges) { } }
class Year : Subexpression { public Year(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(ranges) { } }
```

---

Lastly a few helper extensions:

```
static class RangeExtensions
{
    public static CronRange SetMin(this CronRange range, int min)
    {
        return new CronRange(min, range.Max, range.Step, range.Extension);
    }

    public static CronRange SetMax(this CronRange range, int max)
    {
        return new CronRange(range.Min, max, range.Step, range.Extension);
    }

    public static CronRange SetStep(this CronRange range, int step)
    {
        return new CronRange(range.Min, range.Max, step, range.Extension);
    }

    public static CronRange SetExtension(this CronRange range, CronExtension extension)
    {
        return new CronRange(range.Min, range.Max, range.Step, extension);
    }

    public static CronRange SetMin(this CronRange? range, int min) => range.Value.SetMin(min);

    public static CronRange SetMax(this CronRange? range, int max) => range.Value.SetMax(max);

    public static CronRange SetStep(this CronRange? range, int step) => range.Value.SetStep(step);

    public static CronRange SetExtension(this CronRange? range, CronExtension extension) => range.Value.SetExtension(extension);
}

static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static bool Any(this StringBuilder stringBuilder)
    {
        return stringBuilder.Length > 0;
    }
}
```

---

## Result

This is what I get:

```
Ranges = [{Min = 14 Max = 14 Step = 0 Extension = None}, {Min = 18 Max = 18 Step = 0 Extension = None}, {Min = 3 Max = 39 Step = 3 Extension = None}, {Min = 52 Max = 52 Step = 0 Extension = None}]
Ranges = [{Min = 0 Max = 0 Step = 5 Extension = None}]
Ranges = [{Min = 14 Max = 14 Step = 0 Extension = None}, {Min = 18 Max = 18 Step = 0 Extension = None}, {Min = 3 Max = 39 Step = 0 Extension = None}, {Min = 52 Max = 52 Step = 0 Extension = Weekday}]
Ranges = []
Ranges = [{Min = 1 Max = 1 Step = 0 Extension = None}, {Min = 3 Max = 3 Step = 0 Extension = None}, {Min = 9 Max = 9 Step = 0 Extension = None}]
Ranges = [{Min = 2 Max = 4 Step = 0 Extension = None}, {Min = 6 Max = 6 Step = 0 Extension = Third}]
Ranges = [{Min = 2002 Max = 2010 Step = 0 Extension = None}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a single access modifier on any type, did you *mean* for them all to be `internal`? If so, specify that explicitly.

---

> ```
> var position = (int?)null;
> ```

*Really?* In cases like this (casting `null`) don't use `var`, just specify the type.

---

> ```
> var updateLastTokenType = new Func<Token, Token>(t => { lastTokenType = t.Type; return t; });
> ```

For your use case, this function is not helpful. You update `lastTokenType` manually *as many times* as you update it with this function, and one of the updates you do with this function is undone by a manual update. Just swallow the bullet and replace this with manual updates instead.

---

> ```
> private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> Months = new[]
> {
>     "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
> }
> .Select((month, index) => new { month, index }).ToDictionary(x => x.month, x => x.index + 1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
> ```

Is `MAI` spelled like that? Not `MAY`?

Also, with what this and the property above it do, I would consider wrapping them in a function call that will do that conversion, that's a lot of code to have in an initializer.

---

> ```
> private static IEnumerable<IGrouping<Type, Token>> GroupTokens(IEnumerable<Token> tokens)
> ```

You should be returning `IEnumerable<TokenGrouping>` there, since you are returning objects of that type anyway.

---

> ```
> public static CronRange SetMin(this CronRange? range, int min) => range.Value.SetMin(min);
>
> public static CronRange SetMax(this CronRange? range, int max) => range.Value.SetMax(max);
>
> public static CronRange SetStep(this CronRange? range, int step) => range.Value.SetStep(step);
>
> public static CronRange SetExtension(this CronRange? range, CronExtension extension) => range.Value.SetExtension(extension);
> ```

What happens when I provide `null` here? Easy fix: `range?.Value.Set...`

---

Overall, **excellent** work here. It's always nice to see your questions as they tend to be *very good* code-wise to begin with, the worst I can find here is a few nitpicks. :)

Comment: It can also be written like `var position = default(int?)`.

Comment: The `SetProperty` extension methods for nullable shouldn't be using the `?.` operator, as it hides the underlying issue if any.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> DaysOfWeek = /*...*/
> private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> Months = /*...*/
> ```

You can use the `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat` to extract the name of weekdays and months.

```
// So, you won't defaulting "May" into french.
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> DaysOfWeek = 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Value.ToUpper(), x => x.Index + 1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> Months =
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames
        .Where(x => x != string.Empty) // the array has 13 elements
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Value.ToUpper(), x => x.Index + 1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

---

> ```
> range = range ?? CronRange.Empty.SetMin(value).SetMax(value);
> if (lastTokenType == TokenType.ListItemSeparator)
> {
>     ranges.Add(range.Value);
>     range = CronRange.Empty.SetMin(value).SetMax(value);
> }
>
> if (lastTokenType == TokenType.RangeSeparator)
> {
>     range = range.SetMax(value);
> }
>
> if (lastTokenType == TokenType.StepSeparator)
> {
>     range = range.SetStep(value);
> }
> ```

At first glance, it looked like some kind of awkward fluent syntax. Then, I realised you need immutability.

You should simply expose the properties as get-only from an interface which `CronRange` implements, and upgrade `CronRange` into a `class`.

```
public interface ICronRange
{
    int Min { get; }
    int Max { get; }
    int Step { get; }
    CronExtension Extension { get; }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
internal class CronRange : ICronRange
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Step { get; set; }
    public CronExtension Extension { get; set; }

    // remove the ctor and use the default one

    public override string ToString() => $"Min = {Min} Max = {Max} Step = {Step} Extension = {Extension}";
    private string DebuggerDisplay => ToString();
}
```

---

Substitute `CronRange` for `ICronRange` anywhere it is used in `Subexpression` and its derived classes.

---

And, just use `range.property = ...` directly:

```
private static Subexpression ParseSubexpression(IGrouping<Type, Token> tokenGroup)
{
    //var range = (CronRange?)null;
    var range = default(CronRange);


    //range = range ?? CronRange.Empty.SetMin(value).SetMax(value);
    range = range ?? new CronRange{ min = value, max = value };


    //ranges.Add(range.SetExtension(Extensions[token.Value]));
    range.Extension = token.Value;
    ranges.Add(range)

    range = null;
}
```

Comment: These are very clever techniques, especially the one with the interface trick for _faking_ an immutable type publicly. I have to admit the `default` looks much better now.