# Parsing and evaluating cron expression

Tags: c#, datetime, regex, expression-trees

I wasn't happy with my [last](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/147453/parsing-cron-expression) attempt to parse a cron expression so I simplified it and now I use regex instead. I'd like you to take a look at this solution whether I'm doing something terribly wrong.

---

Here the main class is the `CronExpression` with only two public APIs
- `From` that splits a cron expression fields and call their factories
- `Contains` that passes the `timestamp` to each field that evaluate each date-time-part

```
public class CronExpression : IEnumerable<CronSubexpression>
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<CreateSubExpressionCallback> SubExpressionFactories = new CreateSubExpressionCallback[]
    {
        ranges => new CronSecond(ranges),
        ranges => new CronMinute(ranges),
        ranges => new CronHour(ranges),
        ranges => new CronDayOfMonth(ranges),
        ranges => new CronMonth(ranges),
        ranges => new CronDayOfWeek(ranges),
        ranges => new CronYear(ranges),
    };

    private readonly List<CronSubexpression> _subexpressions;

    private CronExpression(IEnumerable<CronSubexpression> subExpressions)
    {
        _subexpressions = subExpressions.ToList();
    }

    public static CronExpression From(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input)); }

        var subExpressions =
            Regex
                .Split(input, @"\s")
                .Where(f => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(f))
                .Zip(SubExpressionFactories, (field, factory) => new { field, factory })
                .Select(x => x.factory(Regex.Split(x.field, @",").Select(CronRange.From)));

        return new CronExpression(subExpressions);
    }

    public bool Contains(DateTime timestamp) => this.All(x => x.Contains(timestamp));

    public IEnumerator<CronSubexpression> GetEnumerator() => _subexpressions.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public override string ToString() => string.Join(" ", this.Select(x => x.ToString()));
}

internal delegate CronSubexpression CreateSubExpressionCallback(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges);
```

---

Most of the parsing work is done in the `CronRange` class by the `From` methods. They build the regexes and try to match the values either numeric or literal.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
public class CronRange
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> DaysOfWeek = new[]
    {
        "SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"
    }
    .Select((dayOfWeek, index) => new { dayOfWeek, index })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.dayOfWeek, x => x.index + 1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, int> Months = new[]
    {
        "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"
    }
    .Select((month, index) => new { month, index })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.month, x => x.index + 1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public CronRange(int? min, int? max, int? step, CronExtension extension)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max ?? min;
        Step = step;
        Extension = extension;
        if (min.HasValue && max.HasValue && min > max) { throw new ArgumentException("min must be less then max."); }
        if (step.HasValue && step < 1) { throw new ArgumentException("step must be positive."); }
    }

    private static CronRange Empty => new CronRange(null, null, null, CronExtension.None);

    public static IEqualityComparer<CronRange> Comparer { get; } = new CronRangeEqualityComparer();

    public bool IsEmpty => !Min.HasValue;

    public int? Min { get; }

    public int? Max { get; }

    public int? Step { get; }

    public CronExtension Extension { get; }

    private const string Pattern = @"(?<Min>{0})(?:-(?<Max>{0}))?(?:\/(?<Step>{0}))?((?:#(?<nth>[1-5]))|(?<Ext>L|W))?";

    public static CronRange From(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input)); }

        input =
            input
                .NormalizeCronString()
                .CleanUpCronString();

        if (input == "*") { return Empty; }

        return
            FromNumeric(input) ??
            FromLiteral(input) ??
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(input));
    }

    private static CronRange FromNumeric(string input)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(input, string.Format(Pattern, @"\d+"), RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

        if (!match.Success) { return null; }

        var range = Empty;

        if (int.TryParse(match.Groups["Min"].Value, out var min)) range = range.WithMin(min);
        if (int.TryParse(match.Groups["Max"].Value, out var max)) range = range.WithMax(max);
        if (int.TryParse(match.Groups["Step"].Value, out var step)) range = range.WithStep(step);
        if (int.TryParse(match.Groups["nth"].Value, out var nth)) range = range.WithExtension((CronExtension)nth);
        if (Enum.TryParse<CronExtension>(match.Groups["Ext"].Value, out var ext)) range = range.WithExtension(ext);

        return range;
    }

    private static CronRange FromLiteral(string input)
    {
        foreach (var literals in new[] { DaysOfWeek, Months })
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(input, string.Format(Pattern, string.Join("|", literals.Keys)));

            if (!match.Success) { continue; }

            var range = Empty;

            if (literals.TryGetValue(match.Groups["Min"].Value, out var min)) range = range.WithMin(min);
            if (literals.TryGetValue(match.Groups["Max"].Value, out var max)) range = range.WithMax(max);
            if (literals.TryGetValue(match.Groups["Step"].Value, out var step)) range = range.WithStep(step);

            return range;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private string DebuggerDisplay => ToString();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (IsEmpty) { return "*"; }

        return
            new StringBuilder()
                .Append(Min)
                .Append(Max.HasValue && Max > Min ? $"-{Max}" : string.Empty)
                .Append(Step.HasValue ? $"/{Step}" : string.Empty)
                .ToString();
    }
}
```

---

After the parsing the data is stored in a few classes derived from `CronSubexpression`. They mainly provide the valid range for a field. The base class also implements the `Contains` method that requries a date-time-part that the derived classes need to provide. *(In future some of them will additionaly evaluate the cron-expression extensions but I don't need them yet so they are "missing".)*

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebuggerDisplay,nq}")]
public abstract class CronSubexpression : List<CronRange>, IGrouping<CronField, CronRange>
{
    /// <remarks>Duplicate entries are ignored.</remarks>
    protected CronSubexpression(CronField field, IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(ranges.Distinct(CronRange.Comparer))
    {
        Key = field;
        if (ranges == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ranges)); }
        if (this.Count(r => r.IsEmpty) > 1) { throw new ArgumentException(paramName: nameof(ranges), message: $"{Key} can have only one empty range."); }
        if (this.Any(r => r.IsEmpty) && this.Count() > 1) { throw new ArgumentException(paramName: nameof(ranges), message: $"{Key} must not have other ranges if there is an empty one."); }
        if (this.Any(r => r.Min < Min || r.Min > Max)) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(ranges), message: $"{Key} must be between {Min}-{Max}."); }
        if (this.Any(r => r.Max < Min || r.Max > Max)) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(ranges), message: $"{Key} must be between {Min}-{Max}."); }
    }

    public CronField Key { get; }

    public abstract int Min { get; }

    public abstract int Max { get; }

    private string DebuggerDisplay => ToString();

    public bool Contains(DateTime timestamp)
    {
        if (this.Any(x => x.IsEmpty))
        {
            return true;
        }

        var value = GetDatePart(timestamp);

        foreach (var range in this)
        {
            if (range.Min <= value && value <= range.Max)
            {
                if (range.Step.HasValue)
                {
                    var step = range.Step.Value;
                    while (step <= value)
                    {
                        if (value == step) { return true; }
                        step += range.Min.Value;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected abstract int GetDatePart(DateTime timestamp);

    public override string ToString() => string.Join(",", this.Select(se => se.ToString()));
}
```

The concrete implementations for each field:

```
public class CronSecond : CronSubexpression
{
    public CronSecond(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(CronField.Seconds, ranges) { }

    public override int Min => 0;

    public override int Max => 59;

    protected override int GetDatePart(DateTime timestamp) => timestamp.Second;
}

public class CronMinute : CronSubexpression
{
    public CronMinute(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(CronField.Minutes, ranges) { }

    public override int Min => 0;

    public override int Max => 59;

    protected override int GetDatePart(DateTime timestamp) => timestamp.Minute;
}

public class CronHour : CronSubexpression
{
    public CronHour(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(CronField.Hours, ranges) { }

    public override int Min => 0;

    public override int Max => 23;

    protected override int GetDatePart(DateTime timestamp) => timestamp.Hour;
}

public class CronDayOfMonth : CronSubexpression
{
    public CronDayOfMonth(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(CronField.DayOfMonth, ranges) { }

    public override int Min => 1;

    public override int Max => 31;

    protected override int GetDatePart(DateTime timestamp) => timestamp.Day;
}

public class CronMonth : CronSubexpression
{
    public CronMonth(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(CronField.Month, ranges) { }

    public override int Min => 0;

    public override int Max => 11;

    protected override int GetDatePart(DateTime timestamp) => timestamp.Month;
}

public class CronDayOfWeek : CronSubexpression
{
    public CronDayOfWeek(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(CronField.DayOfWeek, ranges) { }

    public override int Min => 1;

    public override int Max => 7;

    protected override int GetDatePart(DateTime timestamp) => (int)timestamp.DayOfWeek;
}

public class CronYear : CronSubexpression
{
    public CronYear(IEnumerable<CronRange> ranges) : base(CronField.Year, ranges) { }

    public override int Min => DateTime.MinValue.Year;

    public override int Max => DateTime.MaxValue.Year;

    protected override int GetDatePart(DateTime timestamp) => timestamp.Year;
}
```

---

There are also a few other supporting classes and extensions that I didn't include in order to not make it a wall-of-code (let me know if I should have).

---

I've also written *a few* unit tests but I'll just post some for the `Seconds` part as they are all quite similar.

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Seconds")]
public void Contains_ExactSecond_True()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(CronExpression.From("2 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 2)));
}

[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Seconds")]
public void Contains_ExactSecond_False()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(CronExpression.From("2 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 3)));
}

[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Seconds")]
public void Contains_SecondRange_True()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(CronExpression.From("2-8 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 2)));
    Assert.IsTrue(CronExpression.From("2-8 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 5)));
    Assert.IsTrue(CronExpression.From("2-8 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 8)));
}

[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Seconds")]
public void Contains_SecondRange_False()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(CronExpression.From("2-8 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 1)));
    Assert.IsFalse(CronExpression.From("2-8 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 9)));
}

[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Seconds")]
public void Contains_SecondRangeWithStep_True()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(CronExpression.From("2-8/2 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 2)));
    Assert.IsTrue(CronExpression.From("2-8/2 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 6)));
    Assert.IsTrue(CronExpression.From("2-8/2 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 8)));
}

[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Seconds")]
public void Contains_SecondRangeWithStep_False()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(CronExpression.From("2-8/2 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 3)));
    Assert.IsFalse(CronExpression.From("2-8/2 * * * * *").Contains(new DateTime(2017, 5, 1, 8, 0, 7)));
}
```

---

I'm going to use this for a scheduler (that I'm going to write after this is ready) so I'd like to hear from you whether I made any major mistakes that will make it less robust and or have any downsides?

Comment: @dfhwze I completely forgot about this one. I'll try to use my brad new tokenizer for that and see how this works.

Comment: Typo: MAI should be MAY. That's probably missing from your test cases. :)

Comment: @RolandIllig ooops, I must have been thinking in German while writing it ;-]

Answer (score 3):

overall looks like a great job.
Still, I wonder if you could save some CPU cycles with replacing `Regex` in favour of `string` methods

```
var subExpressions =
            input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Zip(SubExpressionFactories, (field, factory) => new { field, factory })
                .Select(x => x.factory(x.field.Split(',').Select(CronRange.From)));
```

Comment: I think this possible but I try to avoid string.split like the plague ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t I'd be interested to hear why

Comment: @VisualMelon they're so not cool. Everyone can split and by doing regex you always learn something new ;-P

Comment: @VisualMelon btw, I've heard you like tuples? lol Have you seen [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195417/parsing-small-data-into-tuples) question already?