# Scheduler built with observables

Tags: c#, extension-methods, observer-pattern, scheduled-tasks

I sometimes have to schedule some tasks and wanted to have my own reusable scheduler. Since I like the [Rx](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/00_Foreword.html), I build it on top of it.

---

#### Follow-up

There is a [newer version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192103/scheduler-built-with-observables-v2-follow-up) of the `Scheduler`.

---

The `Scheduler` class is really simple. It's backed by a newer implementation of my old [CronExpression](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164921/parsing-and-evaluating-cron-expression).

There are currently only these two methods. The factory method `Create` creates a new scheduler that ticks at the specified intervals and provides schedules as `DateTime`s to the observers.

Jobs are scheduled with the `Schedule` extension. This one requires a cron-expression and the action to execute.

```
public static class Scheduler
{
    public static IObservable<DateTime> Create(TimeSpan interval, IDateTime dateTime)
    {
        return
            Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                .Select(_ => dateTime.Now());
    }

    public static IDisposable Schedule(this IObservable<DateTime> schedules, string cronExpressionString, Action<DateTime> action)
    {
        var cronExpression = CronExpression.Parse(cronExpressionString);
        return
            schedules
                .Where(cronExpression.Contains)
                .Subscribe(action);
    }
}
```

---

The `DateTime` abstraction is supported by the `IDateTime` interface:

```
public interface IDateTime
{
    DateTime Now();
}
```

which is implemented as

```
public class LocalDateTime : IDateTime
{
    public DateTime Now() => DateTime.Now;
}
```

or

```
public class UtcDateTime : IDateTime
{
    public DateTime Now() => DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

---

#### Example

In order to use it I just create a scheduler, specify what kind of timestamp it should generate and schedule some actions:

```
var scheduler = Scheduler.Create(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), new LocalDateTime());

scheduler.Schedule("0/1 * * * * * *", schedule =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"DEBUG: {schedule} [{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}]");
});

scheduler.Schedule("0/5 * * * * * *", schedule =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ACTION: {schedule}");
});
```

The output is:

```
DEBUG: 13/04/2018 22:32:09 [10]
DEBUG: 13/04/2018 22:32:10 [12]
ACTION: 13/04/2018 22:32:10
DEBUG: 13/04/2018 22:32:11 [10]
DEBUG: 13/04/2018 22:32:12 [14]
DEBUG: 13/04/2018 22:32:13 [8]
DEBUG: 13/04/2018 22:32:14 [12]
ACTION: 13/04/2018 22:32:15
DEBUG: 13/04/2018 22:32:15 [8]
DEBUG: 13/04/2018 22:32:16 [12]
DEBUG: 13/04/2018 22:32:17 [8]
```

---

There seems to be no rocket science here but this might elusive. Can/should this scheduler by improved in any way?

Comment: `.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` you should be using the parameter `interval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> public static IObservable<DateTime> Create(TimeSpan interval, IDateTime dateTime)
> {
>     return
>         Observable
>             .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
>             .Select(_ => dateTime.Now());
> }
> ```

You forgot to plug `interval` parameter. And, I would consider renaming it `resolution`.

I wouldn't trust the values from selecting `DatetTime::Now` or `DateTime::UtcNow`:

```
// try running this for a while
var scheduler = Scheduler.Create(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), new LocalDateTime());
scheduler.Schedule("0/1 * * * * * *", schedule =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ACTION: {schedule}: {schedule:ss.fff}");
});
```

> ```
> ACTION: 2018-04-13 6:28:29 PM: 29.987
> ACTION: 2018-04-13 6:28:30 PM: 30.987
> ACTION: 2018-04-13 6:28:32 PM: 32.001
> ACTION: 2018-04-13 6:28:33 PM: 33.001
> ```

Depending on `CronExpression::Contains` implementation, the scheduler could be skipping task when `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` gets near 0 or 999.

I've attempted to solve that by adding `index * interval` to a snapshot of time, however this solution suffered a problem: The delay is cumulative, so the schedule's time will slowly deviate(fall behind) from the real time:

```
// dont use this
public static IObservable<DateTime> Create2(TimeSpan interval, IDateTime dateTime)
{
    var snapshot = dateTime.Now();
    var offset = interval.Ticks - snapshot.Ticks % interval.Ticks;

    return Observable.Interval(interval)
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromTicks(offset))
        .Select(x => snapshot.AddTicks(interval.Ticks * (x + 1) + offset));
}
```

An better solution would be to provide a range of time, and check if expression fall between the range:

```
public static IDisposable Schedule2(this IObservable<DateTime> schedules, string cronExpressionString, Action<DateTime> action)
{
    var cronExpression = Regex.Match(cronExpressionString, @"^0/(?<s>\d+)");
    return
        schedules
            .Scan(default(TimeRange), (previous, x) => new TimeRange(previous?.End, x))
            .Where(cronExpression.Contains)
            .Subscribe(action);
}

public class TimeRange
{
    public DateTime? Start { get; }
    public DateTime End { get; }

    public TimeRange(DateTime? start, DateTime end)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.End = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: _You forgot to plug interval parameter._ oops, refactoring mistake :-] Since the smallest value of a cron-expression is seconds, I think the milliseconds can be ignored... but I see that I have to take care of the missing ones :-o Could you explain the range approach in more detail? I cannot figure this out :-( but you have my vote!

Answer (score 1):

Xiaoy312 has a point about the risk of missing seconds when using `Interval`. It seems that each "tick" of `Observable.Interval()` waits until the previous returns. So if the OnNext halts the thread a while, the next "tick" is fired too late and you may miss a second or two.

Trying to start each scheduled task on a new thread - for instance via a `System.Timers.Timer` seems to be a bad idea, since the same Cron job probably can not run concurrently(?).

One way not to lose any seconds using `Observable.Interval` is as follows:

```
  Random rand = new Random(5);
  IObservable<Timestamped<long>> source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Timestamp().ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default);

  IDisposable subscription = source.Subscribe(
      x =>
      {
        Console.WriteLine("OnNext: {0}", x);
        Thread.Sleep(rand.Next(0, 4001));
        Console.WriteLine("After Sleep OnNext: {0}", x);
      },
      ex => Console.WriteLine("OnError: {0}", ex.Message),
      () => Console.WriteLine("OnCompleted"));


  Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to unsubscribe...");
  Console.ReadLine();
  subscription.Dispose();
```

This seems to ensure no slip in the sequence of timestamps (Second-wise at least), but each elapsed interval may be (cumulatively) delayed according to previous intervals "laziness". In this way you are not guarantied that the job is done on schedule, but you won't miss a job because of "missing" seconds. It seems though that the time pump catches up the delay when no action delay the current elapsed interval.

Comment: This is an interesting approach but unfortunatelly if you constrain the thread, all worker tasks will execute on the same one. If you get the `x.Timestamp.DateTime` property and format it with milliseconds you'll notice that it suffers from the same inaccuracy as other techniques :-( I've been experimenting with the missing second for some time and I think I might have found how to fix it. I'll post it later but it checks if now is `>1s` from last. If so, I return two timestamps via `SelectMany`. It doesn't matter that I return two at the same time, most important is to not loose it.

Comment: @t3chb0t: OK, it seems to be two different problems then. As I understand/understood `ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)`, each interval should be executed on its own thread, but that is not the case. And it seems not to be the case no matter how you configure Observable.Intervals (?)

Comment: @t3chb0t: You approach with two timestamps seems to be the same as to have an initial start time, and then just iterate over a long representing the second-offset from that start time.

Comment: Observers are executed on their threads without any additional measures. See the output in my question. I write the thread id to the console. Two timestamps aren't the same as incrementing a start date. Because with incrementing it'll be at some point permanently inaccurate, with my approach I use Now, and publish an additional timestamp only once in a while if one was missing due to 15ms resolution of the timers. You can see how this grows by adding milliseconds to the output :-(

Comment: @t3chb0t: Yes, I understand. If you do some time consuming work in the actions, you'll see a different behavior. About the two timestamp approach: I suppose you'll then execute the cron action twice if they differ and both timestamps trigger them. I won't argue, but look forward to see your solution - it's always interesting to see, what you're up to :-). My long-suggestion was an attempt to solve another tick-slip problem, that may not occur in you real environment.